# Axios put is giving OPTIONS 403 forbidden in react

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
saveEditData=()=>{
    const post=this.data.saveData
    return axios.put('url',post)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200)
            console.log(response.data)
    })
}
```

I'm getting `OPTIONS 403 Forbidden 
Failed to load`. Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.
The get request for the same is working fine. What am I doing wrong in PUT request?